# Annual mean using common months over the year for different plots

Tags: r, dplyr

[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfQr6.png)

[data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/107MMwd_qaTpbZdtpJJ1udZnIiNeOEgFv/view?usp=sharing)
Hi,
I have a large dataset like this. I want to calculate the annual mean that I can do by dplyr:

```
    annual_mean<-
              df %>%
              group_by(year) %>% 
              summarise(across(Plot1:Plot3, ~ mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE)))
```

But I need to calculate the annual mean using the months commonly present over the years excluding the NA. For example, in Plot1 may be 2,4,5 and 7 months are common over the years. So, I have to calculate the annual mean only using these months. And then different common months for Plot2, Plot3.

New member!
Any help is highly appreciated!

**Reproducible Sample Data**

```
> dput(head(df, 100))
structure(list(Plot1 = c(0.77, 0.75, 0.75, 0.77, 0.79, 0.8, 0.8, 
0.83, 0.81, 0.85, 0.85, NA, NA, 0.69, 0.66, 0.74, 0.63, 0.65, 
0.65, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.79, 0.8, 0.75, 0.82, 0.8, 0.83, 0.8, 0.82, 
NA, 0.86, 0.8, 0.81, 0.78, 0.78, 0.73, 0.79, 0.74, 0.72, 0.76, 
0.71, 0.71, 0.72, 0.73, 0.71, 0.73, 0.74, 0.79, 0.78, 0.78, 0.83, 
0.8, 0.85, 0.86, 0.78, 0.76, 0.73, 0.72, 0.69, 0.73, 0.65, 0.63, 
0.63, 0.65, 0.69, 0.76, 0.7, 0.7, 0.71, 0.72, 0.77, 0.71, 0.76, 
0.77, 0.78, 0.8, 0.76, 0.76, 0.51, 0.74, 0.71, 0.73, 0.64, 0.65, 
0.63, 0.61, 0.64, 0.71, 0.68, 0.74, 0.7, 0.76, 0.74, 0.71, 0.74, 
0.8, 0.78, 0.79, 0.69), Plot2 = c(NA, 0.38, 0.45, 0.48, 0.76, 
0.88, 0.91, 0.9, 0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 0.84, 0.82, 0.83, 0.67, 0.62, 
0.58, 0.6, 0.57, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.42, 0.48, 0.53, 0.49, 0.51, 
0.66, 0.89, NA, 0.87, 0.88, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.81, 0.69, 0.67, 
0.57, 0.54, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.44, 0.51, 0.48, 0.38, 0.51, 
0.83, 0.91, 0.91, 0.87, 0.89, 0.84, 0.87, 0.58, 0.75, 0.61, 0.55, 
0.55, 0.55, NA, 0.61, 0.6, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.78, 0.87, 
0.91, 0.92, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.89, 0.88, 0.88, 0.82, 0.56, 0.54, 
0.54, 0.57, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.28, NA, 0.69, 0.8, 
0.91), Plot3 = c(NA, 0.77, 0.65, 0.7, 0.61, 0.63, 0.6, 0.59, 
0.55, 0.53, 0.49, 0.44, 0.45, 0.35, 0.48, 0.51, 0.7, 0.63, 0.7, 
0.7, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.38, NA, 0.67, 0.59, 0.59, 0.61, 0.56, 
0.53, 0.54, 0.51, 0.32, 0.37, 0.43, 0.4, 0.67, 0.6, 0.65, 0.67, 
0.72, NA, 0.72, NA, 0.75, 0.7, 0.69, 0.66, 0.62, 0.6, 0.57, 0.54, 
0.54, 0.53, 0.49, 0.33, 0.31, 0.41, 0.46, 0.47, 0.52, 0.69, 0.74, 
0.7, NA, NA, 0.79, NA, 0.72, 0.72, 0.64, 0.6, 0.6, 0.58, 0.58, 
0.54, 0.53, 0.51, 0.51, 0.49, 0.37, 0.51, 0.48, 0.5, 0.64, 0.77, 
NA, NA, 0.78, 0.77, 0.72, NA, 0.68, 0.61, 0.59, 0.62, 0.59, 0.59
), Day = c(18, 5, 21, 6, 22, 8, 24, 9, 25, 11, 27, 12, 28, 13, 
29, 15, 31, 16, 2, 18, 1, 17, 2, 18, 6, 22, 7, 23, 9, 25, 10, 
26, 12, 28, 13, 29, 14, 30, 16, 1, 17, 3, 19, 1, 17, 2, 18, 6, 
22, 7, 23, 9, 25, 10, 26, 12, 28, 13, 29, 14, 30, 16, 1, 17, 
3, 19, 1, 17, 2, 18, 6, 22, 7, 23, 9, 25, 10, 26, 12, 28, 13, 
29, 14, 30, 16, 1, 17, 3, 19, 1, 17, 2, 18, 5, 21, 6, 22, 8, 
24, 9), year = c(2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 
2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 
2000, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 
2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 
2001, 2001, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 
2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 
2002, 2002, 2002, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 
2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 
2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 
2004, 2004, 2004, 2004), months = c(2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 
7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10, 11, 12, 12, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 
5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 11, 11, 12, 12, 1, 1, 2, 2, 
3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 11, 11, 12, 12, 
1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 11, 
11, 12, 12, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6)), row.names = c(NA, 
-100L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! You're more likely to get a helpful solution if you can supply a full reproducible example, including a cut of your data that **isn't** in screenshot form! Please read the [guidance](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for more info. You might consider using `dput(df)` to get a cut of your data to improve your question. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you. I shared the data. Please check the second data link. yes, the first data link is just a screenshot, sorry for this inconvenience.

Comment: Check my updates please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three `Plot` columns and you want to do the same thing with each one. In cases like this you can make your life easier by 'pivoting' the data into 'long' (i.e. 'tidy') format. Here is an approach using `tidyr` and `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

tidied_df <- df %>%
  
  # First pivot into 'long' or 'tidy' format
  pivot_longer(Plot1:Plot3, names_to = "Plot", 
               values_to = "Value", names_prefix = "Plot") %>% 
  
  # First remove all missing values of 'Value'
  filter(!is.na(Value)) %>% 
  
  # Now turn 'implicit' missing months to explicit
  complete(Plot, year, months) %>% 
  
  # Can now add a column indicating whether the whole month is 'missing'
  # for a given year
  group_by(Plot, year, months) %>% 
  mutate(month_missing = all(is.na(Value))) %>% 
  
  # Now use the helper column to remove a month from all years if any
  # one year has only missing values for that month
  group_by(Plot, months) %>% 
  filter(!any(month_missing)) %>% 
  ungroup()
  
# We can take a look to see which months are present across all years
# for each plot like so:
tidied_df %>% 
  group_by(Plot) %>% 
  summarise(
    months = paste(sort(unique(months)), collapse = ", "), 
    .groups = "drop"
  )
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>   Plot  months                         
#>   <chr> <chr>                          
#> 1 1     2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 12
#> 2 2     4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11       
#> 3 3     3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
  

# Finally, we can compute the mean across each plot:
tidied_df %>% 
  group_by(Plot, year) %>% 
  summarise(Value = mean(Value, na.rn = TRUE), .groups = "drop")
#> # A tibble: 57 x 3
#>    Plot   year Value
#>    <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 1      2000 0.749
#>  2 1      2001 0.78 
#>  3 1      2002 0.741
#>  4 1      2003 0.703
#>  5 1      2004 0.734
#>  6 1      2005 0.725
#>  7 1      2006 0.732
#>  8 1      2007 0.725
#>  9 1      2008 0.761
#> 10 1      2009 0.766
#> # … with 47 more rows
```

## Edit

As requested, here is a method to filter for values of `Plot` where all years have at least 4 months in common:

```
tidied_df %>% 
  group_by(Plot) %>% 
  filter(n_distinct(months) > 4) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

Comment: Exactly this is the solution I am looking for. Perfectly Solved!!! Much appreciated. One more thing... Can we please add a condition that only calculates the annual mean if at least 4 months are common over a year?

Comment: Yep, I'll make an edit. Please consider accepting this solution if the main parts of your question are answered! Thanks.

Comment: Your answer perfectly solved the problem. So, I must consider your solution. Can you please tell me where should I put this new condition exactly?

Comment: You can simply put it at the end of the first pipe chain - have a play round with it and try to understand what’s happening, you’ll see that it’s not too complicated.

Answer (score 2):

**Updated**
I have modified my solutions based on what your have requested in comments. This time I first found the common months for each `Plot` and then went on to calculate the mean for every year.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

# I created a character vector of Plot names in order to ease iteration
Plots <- paste("Plot", c(1:3), sep = "")

# Then we iterate over each name selecting only the corresponding column 
# from the original data set and find the common months for each iteration.
Plots %>%
  map(~ df %>% 
        select(.x, months, year) %>%
        drop_na() %>%
        group_split(year) %>%
        map(~ .x %>% 
              select(months) %>%
              distinct()) %>% 
        reduce(~ intersect(.x, .y))) %>%
  set_names(nm = Plots) -> commons
```

Then we use the commons' months to apply a filter on the entire data set:

```
# This time we iterate over both commons and plot names at the same time

map2(Plots, commons, ~ 
       df %>% 
       select(.x, months, year) %>%
       filter(months %in% .y[["months"]]) %>%
       group_by(year) %>%
       summarise(across(starts_with("Plot"), ~ mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE)))) %>%
  exec(cbind, !!!.) %>%
  select(-c(3, 5))


    year Plot1 Plot2 Plot3
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1  2000 0.749 0.771 0.566
 2  2001 0.78  0.724 0.512
 3  2002 0.741 0.707 0.528
 4  2003 0.703 0.806 0.559
 5  2004 0.734 0.757 0.549
 6  2005 0.725 0.758 0.547
 7  2006 0.732 0.796 0.542
 8  2007 0.725 0.763 0.585
 9  2008 0.761 0.736 0.569
10  2009 0.766 0.776 0.575
11  2010 0.768 0.78  0.622
12  2011 0.781 0.787 0.549
13  2012 0.776 0.784 0.553
14  2013 0.774 0.787 0.598
15  2014 0.748 0.809 0.577
16  2015 0.731 0.797 0.587
17  2016 0.758 0.67  0.653
18  2017 0.799 0.76  0.599
19  2018 0.794 0.81  0.575
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this kind and super-fast response! Yes, I am looking for something like this. But,  If I am not wrong these common months are common for all four plots? The common months should be Plot-specific. Not common for all the Plots rather than each plot will have distinct results. Can you help me?

Comment: You mean you would like to separate plots and consider only months that are common in each of them? so every plot has its own common months?

Comment: Yes, exactly! Can I do this at a time? or I need to follow this code for each plot? I have nearly 100 plots!

Comment: What I did was first removing `NA`s for all 3 Plots and then find common months for all of them. Yes it can be done but I will have to take my time.

Comment: @Lincon , I found a way.

Comment: Thank you very much. Much appreciated. It also solved the above problem. But when I am using it for my whole dataset with 100 plots. I get this error:  Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 19, 0
maybe, there are plots without common months. I really don't know how to solve this. Also, I am wondering if I can add a condition that it will only calculate the annual mean only when at least 4 months are common over the years for a specific plot.

Comment: Which part of the code returns that error? It can be fixed.

Comment: In the map2 part.

Comment: Nothing specific happens there just bear in mind to modify `Plots` vector with the number of actual `Plot`s variable you have in this case we have only 3. Try running `map2` part without the last two lines and let me know. I spent a considerable amount of time on this which is appreciated though but don't want to leave it unfinished.

Comment: Yes, I changed the actual plot variable. And you are right, the problem comes with cbind. without the last two lines, I get the results for all the plots

Comment: Oh great! glad to hear it finally worked. Maybe the problem is with `exec` function which I only think of updating your `rlang` package but I used to have a data frame output.

Comment: You did a great job. Thank you very much for your time and kind help, though updating rlang didn't work for me to solve exec function problem somehow. This is actually my problem, I am not that good at R. You are so expert, I can feel it to see your code!!!

Comment: @Lincon Thank you very much, it's very kind of you. No I'm actually not an expert as this time last year I didn't know what R is. In time you will be maybe even better than me. Please consider upvotting all the answers that solved your problem and choose whichever one you like. It was after all a great learning experience for me.